# Nested problems in Openmdao2

Tags: python-3.x, openmdao

We want to make a nested problem in openmdao2

The toplevel problem:
 - generate initial parameters for the subproblem using the DOEDriver

Subproblem:
 - optimize the parameters using ScipyOptimizedriver

There is an example for openmdao1.7 (https://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.3/usr-guide/tutorials/subproblem.html), but the subproblem is not present in openmdao2.

Is it possible to do in an other way in openmdao2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in subproblem support in OpenMDAO2 as of version 2.3. For your specific case, all you have to do is write your own component wrapper for the problem you want to use as a sub-problem.

Alternatively, you could consider writing your own custom driver that combined the DOE driver and optimizers.